# Generating variable names and getters from member expression

Tags: c#, generics, expression-trees

I have a JSON configuration file where the user is allowed to use inside strings certain placeholders `{Type.Name}` that later will be interpolated with the actual values (for connection strings, titles, texts, summaries etc.).

For example in report settings he might want to use the `TestCase.Severity`value

> "Title": "{TestCase.Severity}",

Each variable consists of the name of the declaring type and the name of the property.

I did not want to hardcode those properties (there are a lot more of them) so I build a `VariableBuilder`. It uses a simple member and getter expression to generate names and resolve values. The variables are stored in a dictionary keyed with the declaring type and a hash-set that keeps a type variables.

```
internal class VariableBuilder
{
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, HashSet<INameable>> _variables = new Dictionary<Type, HashSet<INameable>>();

    public void AddVariable<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
    {
        if (expression.Body is MemberExpression memberExpression)
        {
            var variableName = $"{memberExpression.Member.DeclaringType.Name}.{memberExpression.Member.Name}";

            var instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "obj");
            var property = Expression.Property(instance, memberExpression.Member.Name);
            var getValue = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(property, instance).Compile();

            if (_variables.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var variables))
            {
                if (!variables.Add(Variable<T>.Create(variableName, getValue)))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException($"Variable \"{variableName}\" has already been added.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _variables.Add(typeof(T), new HashSet<INameable> { Variable<T>.Create(variableName, getValue) });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Expression must be a member expression.");
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> ResolveVariables<T>(T obj)
    {
        if (_variables.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var variables))
        {
            foreach (var variable in variables.Cast<Variable<T>>())
            {
                yield return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(variable.Name, variable.GetValue(obj));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

To prevent name conflicts I use the `INameable` interface that requires the `Variable<T>` to also implement the `IEquatable` interface so that the hash-set can do its job right.

```
internal interface INameable : IEquatable<INameable>
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

The actual variable name and the getter func are stored by the `Variable<T>`.

```
internal class Variable<T> : INameable
{
    private Variable(string name, Func<T, object> getValue)
    {
        Name = name;
        GetValue = getValue;
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public Func<T, object> GetValue { get; }

    public static INameable Create(string name, Func<T, object> getValue)
    {
        return new Variable<T>(name, getValue);
    }

    public bool Equals(INameable nameable)
    {
        return Name.Equals(nameable.Name);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => Name.GetHashCode();
}
```

---

Here are a few examples of how I use it. When a test is run and a report should be generated I pass the actual test objects to the variable-builder that resolves the final values and later during report generation another *utility* (`VariableResolver`) can interpolate them into strings.

```
var variableReader = new VariableBuilder();
variableReader.AddVariable<TestFile>(x => x.Name);
//variableReader.AddVariable<TestFile>(x => x.Name); // throws because of duplicte key
variableReader.AddVariable<TestUnit>(x => x.Filter);

var testFile = new TestFile { Name = "foo" };
var testUnit = new TestUnit { Filter = "bar" };

var testFileVariables = variableReader.ResolveVariables(testFile);
var testUnitVariables = variableReader.ResolveVariables(testUnit);
```

The two types used in the above example (those are not some *test* objects, the names are real but the actual objects just have a few more properties):

```
internal class TestFile
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

internal class TestUnit
{
    public string Filter { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If someone is curious how such an configuration might look like,
 here's an [example](https://github.com/he-dev/Gunter/blob/master/Gunter/_Tests/Gunter.Tests.Gunter.example.json).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Unnecessary expression trees

`Expression.Compile()` is quite slow, on top of that it requires you to create some extra variables in order to be able to create the expression tree which you later compile to a delegate. Why not create the delegate right away?

I'm still getting used to the C# 7 features but this should be a proper declaration of a local function:

```
object GetValue(T t) => t.GetType().GetProperty(memberExpression.Member.Name).GetValue(t);
```

### Accessing the type name shortly

You can replace `memberExpression.Member.DeclaringType.Name` with `typeof(T).Name` as the declaring type will always be the generic argument in your expression.

### Reducing the nesting

You can invert the first condition in your `AddVariable<T>` to reduce the nesting and shorten the method:

```
if (!(expression.Body is MemberExpression memberExpression))
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Expression must be a member expression.");
}
/...
```

### *LINQ* instead of `foreach`

You can transform your `ResolveVariables` method into a LINQ version, which doesn't use an iterator which looks better to me:

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> ResolveVariables<T>(T obj)
{
    if (_variables.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var variables))
    {
        return variables.Cast<Variable<T>>()
            .Select(t => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(t.Name, t.GetValue(obj)));
    }
    return Enumerable.Empty<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
}
```

**Quotation marks**

It looks clearer using a verbatim string when you want to add quotations:

```
throw new ArgumentException($@"Variable ""{variableName}"" has already been added.");
```

vs

```
throw new ArgumentException($"Variable \"{variableName}\" has already been added.");
```

Is it really necessary to throw an exception here tho? Why not just let it slide..

### Poor equality check

I'm not sure if that simplified version of your class but if that's how it looks, at the very least you should do some null checks, as both `Name` and `nameable` can be null and this will throw an exception which violates the guidelines for overriding `Equals()`. Something along those lines should be more stable:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        return ((Name != null ? Name.GetHashCode() : 0) * 397) ^
                (GetValue != null ? GetValue.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
}

protected bool Equals(Variable<T> other)
{
    return string.Equals(Name, other.Name);
}

public bool Equals(INameable other)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return other.GetType() == GetType() && Equals((Variable<T>) other);
}
```

You can change it a bit for example returning `base.GetHashCode()` instead of 0 if some value is null. And for this simple class you can even get rid of the `protected` Equals method, I prefer having it tho, because if the logic gets complicated it is separated and the public method is easier to read.

Comment: Just a few comments. I use the `Compile` only once per property when the application loads so this time it's not a big performance consideration. Without expressions I won't be able to get the values later. I don't know how to create the `Fun<>` to get those value otherwise (correct me if I missed something in your answers).

Comment: The equality check is correct ;-) I'm interested only in the name. This and the exception is for me so that I don't create variables twice. The value is resolved later when I know the actual instance that will provide a value. I don't know them when the program starts. They are known after tests are run and just before reports are generated. There can be several tests with different conditions, messages, severities and expressions, see [example](https://github.com/he-dev/Gunter/blob/master/Gunter/_Tests/Gunter.Tests.Gunter.example.json).

Comment: [this](https://github.com/he-dev/Gunter/blob/master/Gunter/TehCodez/Data/VariableName.cs) is how I define them now. Everything is hardcoded and is very inconvenient to extend which is why I want to create the `Func`s first and later just pass the instances and generate the names when the program start and resolve values later.

Comment: One line after the comment about the expression tree, I included an example solution with a local function. If you really feel like throwing exceptions is the better option in the `Equals` method fine but to me it seems inconsistent as other types wont exhibit the same behavior on this same method. It's like returning 1, 2, 3 from `CompareTo` when implementing `IComparable<>` because you decided -1, 0, 1 didn't fit your solution. You can do that but it doesn't sound right.

Comment: Well, the `Equals` method does not throw, its only job is to tell whether two names are _equal_ ;-) because I don't want to have any variable twice and that's why I use a hash-set - it understands `IEquatable` and its `Add` method returns true/false after asking the interface what it should do with the new item. It's for me and the exception is going to be thrown if I made a mistake so the application won't start.

Comment: Would you like to continue this discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60381/throwing-exceptions-in-equals-implementation) @t3chb0t?